# How to declare variables in dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to declare two variables within a `dataclass` (`y_set_max` and `y_set_min`). Below is my code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Ymax_ymin: #has to be object inside the brackets
    y_default_max: int #500
    y_default_min: int #0
    current: int
    recommended: int

    def __post_init__(self):
          self.y_set_max = max(y_default_max,current,recommended)
          self.y_set_min = min(y_default_min,current,recommended)

current = 800
recommended = 650

set_axis = Ymax_ymin(500,0,current,recommended)

print(set_axis.y_set_max)
print(set_axis.y_set_min)
```

This is throwing the error: NameError: name `y_default_max` is not defined

How can I modify my `dataclass` code so the two print statements are returned?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `self.y_default_max`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access attributes of an instance, you need to include the instance in the call. While the `dataclass` definition hides the constructor from you where the `y_default_max` that is passed in is read into `self.y_default_max`, it still takes place, and if you want the instance attributes, you need to include the `self.`.

Also, if you want to compute a `dataclass`' attribute based on others, you can use `init=False` to declare it and still get type hints etc. for it:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class YmaxYmin:
    current: int
    recommended: int
    y_default_max: int = 500
    y_default_min: int = 0
    y_set_max: int = field(init=False)
    y_set_min: int = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.y_set_max = max(self.y_default_max, self.current, self.recommended)
        self.y_set_min = min(self.y_default_min, self.current, self.recommended)
```

Given this class definition, your initial statements will run properly:

```
set_axis = YmaxYmin(current=500, recommended=0, y_default_max=800, y_default_min=650)

print(set_axis.y_set_max)  # prints 800
print(set_axis.y_set_min)  # prints 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is the same as with type hinting and default arguments:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Ymax_ymin: #has to be object inside the brackets
    current: int
    recommended: int
    y_default_max: int = 500
    y_default_min: int = 0

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.y_set_max = max(self.y_default_max, current, recommended)
        self.y_set_min = min(self.y_default_min, current, recommended)

current = 800
recommended = 650

set_axis = Ymax_ymin(500, 0, current, recommended)

print(set_axis.y_set_max)
print(set_axis.y_set_min)
```

Note that default arguments must come last. Also, you were missing `self` in `__post_init__`.

Comment: Shouldn't `y_set_max` and `y_set_min` be included in the main dataclass body with `field(init=False)`?

Comment: Yeah, they should. It also can only see `current` and `recommended` because they are global, the instance attributes are ignored...